# how can I check the one element in list has repeated three times In dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the list of elements in flutter like this in dart:

`[3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1]`

I want to this:
if  '1' element of this list is repeated three times then do something.
as you see '1' number has been repeated three times.

Comment: use this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
void main() {
  List<int> myList = [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1];

  // Count the occurrences of '1' in the list
  int countOfOnes = myList.where((element) => element == 1).length;

  // Check if '1' is repeated three times
  if (countOfOnes == 3) {
    // Do something
    print("The element '1' is repeated three times.");
  } else {
    // Do something else
    print("The element '1' is not repeated three times.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  List<int> numbers = [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1];
  int count = 0;

  for (int number in numbers) {
    if (number == 1) {
      count++;
      if (count == 3) {
        print("The number '1' is repeated three times.");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

void main() {
List numbers = [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1];

// Create a map to count occurrences
Map<int, int> counts = {};

```
for (var number in numbers) {
    counts[number] = (counts[number] ?? 0) + 1;
}

bool hasRepeatedThreeTimes = counts.values.any((value) => value >= 3);

print(hasRepeatedThreeTimes);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  List<int> numbers = [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1];
  int targetElement = 1;
  int repetitionCount = 3;
   print(isElementRepeated(numbers,3,2));
}

bool isElementRepeated(List<int> numbers, int targetElement, int repetitionCount) {
  int count = numbers.fold(0, (int acc, int element) {
    return element == targetElement ? acc + 1 : acc;
  });

  return count == repetitionCount;
}
```